# How binary predicate works?

Tags: c++, merge, stl

In the following code, in the binary predicate function mycomparison, why first is getting the first item from L2 (which is 2.1) and not from L1 (1.4)? Similarly, second is getting the first item from L1. And is this behavior specific to this function (merge) or can be extended to other functions. Can we assume that the order of containers, will determine the order being passed to a binary predicate function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
bool mycomparison(double first, double second)
{
    std::cout <<"first "<< first << " " << "second "<< second << "\n"; 
    return (int (first) <  int (second) );
}

int main()
{
    std::list<double> L1, L2;
    L1.push_back(3.1); L1.push_back(2.2); L1.push_back(2.9);
    L2.push_back(3.7); L2.push_back(7.1); L2.push_back(1.4);
    L1.sort(); L2.sort();
    L1.merge(L2);

    std::cout << "L1 contains: ";
    for (std::list<double>::iterator it = L1.begin(); it != L1.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << ",  ";
    std::cout << '\n'; 

    L2.push_back(2.1);
    L2.push_back(3.2);

    std::cout << "L2 contains: ";
    for (std::list<double>::iterator it = L2.begin(); it != L2.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << ",  ";
    std::cout << '\n';

    L1.merge(L2, mycomparison);

    std::cout << "L1 contains: ";
    for (std::list<double>::iterator it = L1.begin(); it != L1.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << ",  ";
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
L1 contains: 1.4,  2.2,  2.9,  3.1,  3.7,  7.1,  
L2 contains: 2.1,  3.2,  
first 2.1 second 1.4
first 2.1 second 2.2
first 2.1 second 2.9
first 2.1 second 3.1
first 3.2 second 3.1
first 3.2 second 3.7
first 3.2 second 7.1
L1 contains: 1.4,  2.2,  2.9,  2.1,  3.1,  3.7,  3.2,  7.1,
```

And here is a sort function that use a binary predicate or Compare. However, the items passed to the function are also "not in order". In myfunction variable i will get the second item in the vector (71) and not the first item (32). Why?

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector

bool myfunction(int i, int j) { 
    std::cout << i << " " <<j<<"\n" ; 
    return (i<j); }

int main() {
    int myints[] = { 32,71,12,45 };
    std::vector<int> myvector(myints, myints + 4);               

    std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myfunction); 

    std::cout << "myvector contains:";
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
71 32
71 32
12 32
45 12
45 71
45 32
myvector contains: 12 32 45 71
```

Comment: No you can not rely on in which order your predicate will be called, or with what arguments. As long as a standard algorithm function fulfills the specified requirements, it might be implemented any possible way.

Comment: By the way, your comparison function doesn't fulfill the [strict weak ordering relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) requirement of [comparison functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare), because of your casts to `int` which truncates the floating point values. Your casting means that from your functions point of view, `2.1 == 2.2 && 2.1 == 2.9 && 2.2 == 2.9`.

Comment: @Thomas Lee  The problem is that after additional adding elements to L2 it  becomes unsorted.

Comment: not sure, but I think if your comparison function did fullfil strict weak ordering and you didnt print the values, you could not tell the difference if merge is calling `myComparison(a,b)` or `myComparison(b,a)`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I don't see which rule it breaks, `2.4f` will be equivalent to `2.7f`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Well, if the OP didn't expect the result to be fully sorted then yes it works. But if the OP expected the result to *be* sorted correctly then the function is wrong. If, for some reason, the requirements states that `2.1 == 2.2 && 2.1 == 2.9 && 2.2 == 2.9` is true, then it works as intended.

Comment: To the OP (Thomas Lee): Can you please elaborate on your problem? What is your *actual* question? About the behavior of predicates in general? About the sorting of the result? About something else?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude behavior of predicates, the sort is the easy part. Unary predicate is clear. In the above binary predicate function mycomparison, why first is getting the first item from L2 (which is 2.1) and not from L1 (1.4)?

Comment: Okay, then my first comment stands. It's simply implementation-specific.

Comment: @aschepler That is a requirement from the specification. But the question is why the elements from `L2` was used as the first argument in the predicate, and the elements from `L1` was used for the second. Why not the opposite? That *is* implementation specific.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so is valid for all binary predicates or some of them? Is there a way to know the order or arguments that will be sent to a predicate function or is it just trial and error?!

Comment: Trial and error, to learn it for *one specific version of one specific compiler and standard library*. It might change in the next version of the same compiler. And, as has been asked before, ***why*** are you asking this? Do you have some code depending on the arguments or some specific ordering? Or is it just plain curiosity (in which case the *only* possible answer is "it's implementation-specific" and nothing else)? This really is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I need to know it to design a binary predicate function, so I know what I am comparing. I tried it on a different compiler and initially values for first and second were from L1 only, then it started to compare L1 with L2. However, the values of first are still from L2 and not from L1. I think this is a confusing design. Typically, one would think that arguments will be sent in order of containers but this was not the case.

Comment: From [this `std::list::merge` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/merge) (about the comparison function): "comparison function ... which returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second." That's it. That's really all you need to know how to make a working comparison function for `merge`. And if ordinary "less than" (the `<` operator) is okay, then don't provide a comparison predicate at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [Strict Weak Ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) such as the one you defined with your `mycomparison` function, it's possible for two objects to be unequal but "equivalent".  In your case, since `mycomparison(2.2, 2.1)` and `mycomparison(2.1, 2.2)` are both false, the numbers `2.1` and `2.2` are equivalent in that ordering.

So the final order of `L1` is in fact sorted according to the `mycomparison` ordering, since `2.2`, `2.9`, and `2.1` are all considered equivalent.  Also, [`std::list::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/merge) guarantees that the elements which were already in `*this` (`2.2` and `2.9`) come before equivalent elements moved from the argument list (`2.1`).  You can see this behavior was also obeyed.